# Problems with New Membership Status; Expiration Date Format

Tags: civimember

I'm having two issues, one chronic and one nice to have.

Chronic: All *new* memberships with completed payments are left in **pending** status. Renewed memberships do not have this issue.

Nice to Have: Is there a way to change the format of a expiration date when it is exported. I need dd/mm/yy and the export (and database) is dd-mm-yy

CiviCRM 5.46.1
Joomla 3.10.6

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about how the payments are recorded. Also check your membership status settings. Have you changed these?

Comment: Payments are through PayPal and the IPN is in the CiviCRM log. I've tried changing the pending status start and end dates, but then reverted back to default. It's made no difference. What is interesting is that in the membership record of this most recent experience, the activity log shows the membership status as 'scheduled', which is different than before